# Using synthetic division for higher powers

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

> Use synthetic division to divide $7x^9-15x^6-3x^3+10$ by $x^3-3$.

I thought synthetic division only works for equation of the form $ax\pm b$, how does it work for higher powers?

Comment: Hint: substitute $x^3=y$.

Comment: I know how to do it now, thanks!

Comment: You just may use synthetic division with  this condition.